# Sort a move to end list

Tags: sorting

A sequential unique list of numbers (1,2,3,...,n) has been randomized and I need to sort it by moving one item at a time to the end of the list.  Which algorithm will provide the least number of moves?

Note: [123645] can be sorted with 1 move, [125346] in 2 moves, [654321] will need 5 moves.  I'd like an algorithm that can account for these, not one that just gives me n-1 all the time.

Best I can think of:

```
for(var x=1; x<=list.length; x++)
if indexOf(x+1)<indexOf(x) then move x+1 to end
```

Does this work?  Best solution?

Comment: It doesn't matter which language it is. The OP just needs an algorithm that would do what he wants in least number of steps.

Comment: Is you list initially sorted? If yes, it's a very easy problem and can be done in less than `n` steps.

Comment: I can represent each element in the list with its index, so yeah, say it is initially sorted by increasing order.

Comment: I modified the description to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my second solution:

```
function mysort(array) {
    var index, value, badValues,
        len = array.length;
    // find values at a bad place
    badValues = [];
    for (index = 0; index < len; index++) {
        if (array[index] !== index + 1 - badValues.length) {
            badValues.push(array[index]);
        }
    }    
    // move those to the end in increasing order
    while (badValues.length > 0) {
        // minimum bad value
        value = Math.min.apply(null, badValues);
        index = array.indexOf(value);        
        // move to the end
        array.splice(index, 1);
        array.push(value);
        // one bad solved
        badValues.splice(badValues.indexOf(value), 1);    
    }
    return array;    
}
```

Here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V664v/3/).
As you can see, the input `[1,2,9,3,4,8,5,6,7]` is sorted by 2 moves, and a fully random, or reversed list is still `n-1` moves.

Comment: You're welcome. I was kinda embarrassed about my first attempt, so I had to solve this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an algorithm:

1. Check the length of the list (from the beginning) till which it is increasing, i.e., stop when the list starts to decrease.
2. Subtract that length from the length of the list. And that is your answer.

Quite intuitive, just think about it.
Example:

```
12345 -> 25341
|25| is in increasing order and after that it becomes decreasing.
Length (2,5) = 2
Answer = 5 - 2 = 3
```

If your list isn't sorted in increasing order, you could always map it via indices.

Comment: I'm a little confused, 25341 needs 4 moves to sort, 25341 => 53412 => 54123 => 51234 => 12345.  How can you sort that list in 3 moves?

Comment: I did the inverse thing. For the forward thing, map `2->1, 5->2, 3->3, 4->4, 1->5`. Then your problem becomes `12345->51342` which needs four steps.

Comment: @user433342 See, it works!! As I said, you can only apply the algorithm to a list sorted in increasing order. Else, you'll have to map it via indices.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, it’s the simplest (and I just got it by myself in a job interview ;) )

Comment: int mySort(int[] A) { int max = 0; for (int i=0; i < A.Length; ++i) { if (A[i] == max + 1) { ++max; } } return A.Length - max; }