# What is the name of the algorithm that can only move elements to the end of a list?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I have tried googling this but no luck.

Basically, this algorithm can only move elements to the end of an array to obtain the desired result from an original list.

For example, the desired list is `desired_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]` and the original list is `initial_list = [4, 2, 3, 1]`, is there an algorithm that can sort the `original_list` to obtain the `desired_list` by only moving elements in the original list to the end of the list?

Comment: is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809986/sort-a-move-to-end-list 
I searched google for `sorting algorithm move to end of list`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a move to end list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809986/sort-a-move-to-end-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've described a selection sort: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort but moving to the opposite end compared with the conventional way (this isn't important, the outcome is the same).